# Check if its the first checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes like so:

```
<div class="checkbox-list">
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="" /> All items</label><br />
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" /> First item</label><br />
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="2" /> Second item</label><br />
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="3" /> Third item</label><br />
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="4" /> Forth Checkbox</label>
</div>
```

The behavior I am looking for is if I select the first checkbox in this `div` (`.checkbox-list input[type=checkbox]:first`) all other checkboxes after is checked off. Likewise if I select any other than the first, the first one is deselected.

I am struggling on how to check if the first one is clicked on?

```
$(".checkbox-list").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function () {
    if ($(this).first()) { // <- not working - how do I know if I clicked the first one?
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked", ".checkbox-list").not(this).prop("checked", false);
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
         // Uncheck first checkbox
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle if you wish to play around: http://jsfiddle.net/4c7aubqL/1/

Comment: Just a quick one: are you checkboxes created dynamically?

Comment: Yes, populated from ajax

Comment: In that case I had do edit my answer to keep events alive using the proper `.on()` delegation (just like you did). Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/sumubuyiga/2/edit)***

```
$(".checkbox-list").on("change", ":checkbox", function() {
    var $all   = $(".checkbox-list").find(":checkbox");
    var $first = $all.eq(0);
    if ($first.is(":checked")) { 
        $all.not(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: This did it, I added a `else { $first.prop("checked", true); }` to make sure it could not be unchecked.

Comment: With that `else` you'll just make a big mistake:  http://jsbin.com/sumubuyiga/3/edit it toggles continuously the $first.

Comment: Ah ha, I see.. Did not even notice!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using radio buttons, not checkboxes. That will do exactly what you want, with no additional effort on your part. Even if you succeed in what you are trying to do, the user interface will look wrong.

Comment: lol, i got now, that's why it is downvote to other answers! :) great!! seeking for proper guidence. but it needs to be downvote to Question itself!

Comment: It should be able to check multiple checkboxes :-)